# JetBrains Rider attach to w3wp.exe process?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Is it possible to have shortcut keyboard stroke to attach to running w3p.exe process with JetBrains Rider?

This will make attaching to running process much more convenient. With Visual Studio there is extension attach to any that makes this setup/approach much easier.

Comment: Hey, which VS extension are you talking about? Is it about [ReAttach](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach)?

Comment: I use AttachToAny

Comment: For now, there isn't anything that would help in this particular task. You just invoke the attach dialog and select a w3wp process there. There're plans to improve the situation, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-27833